# How to obtain sent SMS price

Tags: java, android, sms

Is there way on Android to obtain cost of SMS after sending it programmaticaly?
It would be really nice to know.

Thing is that for example my carrier always sends notification back with remaining credit, but I cannot rely on that every carrier does the same, and parsing it wouldn't be good idea anyway, as there are many different languages in world and text might be formatted differently depending on carrier.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there's no way to determine that as it's all handled on the network side.

Answer (score 0):

There is impossible to determine pricing on subscriber site using standard android SDK API, price known only on operator's side inside its billing system. But, maybe your mobile operator provides an API for receiving bills and only then you it will be possible to define price you charged.

Also, if it is possible to check your balance using USSD or SMS, you may try requesting balance before sending SMS and after.